# CodedUI Keyboard.SendKeys() not working with Special character

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am inserting value to a Windows security Form. However while using Keyboard.SendKeys() with some special character it opens Server Explorer.
Piece of code i am running.

```
                WinWindow securityWindow = new WinWindow();
                securityWindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Windows Security";           

                WinEdit username = new WinEdit(securityWindow);
                username.SearchProperties[WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name] = "User name";

                WinEdit password = new WinEdit(securityWindow);
                password.SearchProperties[WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name] = "Password";

                Keyboard.SendKeys(username,"Admin");
                Mouse.Click(password); 

                Keyboard.SendKeys("Winter#123");
```

I am working on a Windows Server machine and When script tries to Enter **Winter#123** to textbox, it enters upto **Winter#1** and then opens Server Explorer. Hence Login got failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `Keyboard.SendKeys("Winter{#}123");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Sendkeys.SendWait. It would wait for a fraction of second before entering the next character